# How to stop this computation?

Tags: manipulate, front-end, evaluation, dynamic, button

I want to implement start-stop dynamics within a `Manipulate` environment so that, when I click a "Start" button, the simulation starts, and when I click the "Stop" button, it stops. For a simple function `f` that only yields a pause, the following code does what I want

```
Manipulate[update;
 Which[
  run == 0, frame = "Ready to start",
  run == 1, frame = "Simulating..."; run = 2; update = 1 - update,
  run == 2, f[2]; run = 3; update = 1 - update,
  run == 3, frame = "Done"];
 frame,
 Dynamic@If[run == 0 || run == 3,
   Button["Start", run = 1; update = 1 - update],
   Button["Stop", FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorAbort"]; run = 0; 
    update = 1 - update]],
 {{update, 0}, ControlType -> None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {update},
 Initialization :> (run = 0; f = Function[x, Pause[5]]), 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

However, when `f` is more complex (for example solving a huge system of ODEs) this approach doesn't always work. That is, `FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorAbort"]` is evaluated, but the content doesn't change back to the original idle frame. All computations are aborted and the buttons are no longer enabled. Any ideas on how to improve this?

I also suspect there must be an easier of doing this. I'd like to keep `Manipulate` as my main dynamic tool. Could `DynamicModule` facilitate this somehow? What I'm really looking for is full control of the evaluation within `Manipulate`, independently of how complex `f` is.

Comment: "It doesn't always work" because: Sometimes the variable "update" exceeds the recursion limit. Message: RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of -update.

Comment: @hieron I couldn't post my example here as it is indeed a very long function, but thanks for the example! In my case I actually don't get any message, the cell simply stops being evaluated and the placeholder "Simulating..." text remains. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a second variant using CheckAbort (little bit shorter):

```
Manipulate[While[update, frame = "Simulating..."; frame = CheckAbort[
    simulate@3; update = False; "Done",
    update = False; "Ready for start"]
  ]; Dynamic@frame,
 
 Dynamic@Button[
   PaneSelector[{True -> "Stop", False -> "Start"}, Dynamic@update], 
   If[update, FrontEndTokenExecute@"EvaluatorAbort", update = True]],
 
 {{update, False}, {True, False}, ControlType -> None},
 Initialization :> {frame = "Ready for start", 
   simulate[s_] := Pause@s},
 ControlPlacement -> Left, ContentSize -> 150]
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested under:
"11 and 12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)".
Seems ok now. For your old version: To find out, if you exceed the recursion limit, you just remove "ControlType->None" in update, then the message will appear, as soon as recursion limit exceeds.

```
Manipulate[
 While[update,
  Which[
   run == 0, frame = "Ready to start",
   run == 1, frame = "Simulating..."; simulate@3; run = 2,
   run == 2, update = False; frame = "Done"
   ]]; Dynamic@frame,
 
 Dynamic@If[run == 0 || run == 2, 
   Button["Start", run = 1; update = True],
   Button["Stop", run = 0; update = False; frame = "Ready to start";
    FrontEndTokenExecute@"EvaluatorAbort"]],
 
 {{update, False}, {True, False}, ControlType -> None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {update},
 Initialization :> {run = 0, frame = "Ready to start", 
   simulate[x_] := Pause[x]},
 ControlPlacement -> Left, ContentSize -> 150]
```